# Form validation return white label error page

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-boot-2

I tried to do a form validation using spring boot 2.2 and thymeleaf like the documentation example (https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) but I have a white label error page when wrong value are submitted when I should have a binding of these errors in my form view. How to fix that ?

My controller action code:

```
@Controller
public class TodoController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/todo/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String tplTodoCreate(Model model) {
        TodoForm todoForm = new TodoForm();
        return "v-todo-create";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/todo/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String tplTodoCreatePost(@ModelAttribute(name="formTodo") @Valid TodoForm todoForm, RedirectAttributes redirAttrs, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "v-todo-create";
        }

        todoRepository.save(todoForm);
        redirAttrs.addFlashAttribute("msgNotices", "Todo task created successfuly.");
        return "redirect:/todos";
    }
}
```

and the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorator="tpl-default">
<head>
    <title th:text="#{ctl-todo.create.meta.title}">Create New Todo</title>
    <link th:href="@{/css/todo/create.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" layout:fragment="content">
        <h2 class="page-header" th:text="#{ctl-todo.create.00001strid}">Add Todo</h2>
        <form name="todo" method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/todo/create}" th:object="${todoForm}" class="my-form-class">
            <div id="form">
                <div>
                    <label for="form_name" class="required" th:text="#{ctl-todo.create.00002strid}">Name</label>
                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"></p>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="form_name" name="name" min="1" max="30" required="required" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:15px;" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" id="form_save" name="save" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:15px;" th:text="#{ctl-todo.create.00013strid}">Create Todo</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <hr />
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="/todos"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span> <span th:text="#{ctl-todo.create.00014strid}">Back to todos list</span></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The stacktrace is:

```
2020-01-06 21:47:30.780  WARN 12140 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'formTodo' on field 'name': rejected value [a]; codes [Size.formTodo.name,Size.name,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [formTodo.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name],30,2]; default message [size must be between 2 and 30]]
```

Whiteblabel error page is:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jan 07 10:08:07 GMT+01:00 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='formTodo'. Error count: 1
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'formTodo' on field 'name': rejected value [a]; codes [Size.formTodo.name,Size.name,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [formTodo.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name],30,2]; default message [size must be between 2 and 30]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Typicaly the name field have min attribute equals to 1 but the TodoForm entity have a Size constraint with min=2 and max=30. When I test to submit a value with only one character, the good error is detected but that return the error as a white label page rather than the view with the error.

**EDIT:** Probleme solved. It's caused by the order of parameter into the tplTodoCreatePost() method and the @ModelAttribute(name="formTodo"). The method signature was modifed as `public String tplTodoCreatePost(@Valid TodoForm todoForm, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirAttrs)`

Comment: can u please show the code you have? Both view and the controller

Comment: I edited the question to add the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to add a parameter to the model. But it's quite diffcult to troubleshoot without a stack trace. Could you please attach it to your post? Also the rest of the Controller, with GET method mapping could be helpful here.

EDIT:

I think the problem is the order of the parameters of the `tplTodoCreatePost` method. Please try to move `BindingResult` before `Model`, as below:

```
public String tplTodoCreatePost(@Valid TodoForm todoForm, BindingResult result, @ModelAttribute(name="formTodo"), RedirectAttributes redirAttrs, ) {
    // method body
}
```

Comment: I edited the question with the extra informations. I tested with the model.addAttribute you purpose but I have the same result

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please try to reorder the paramters of the method. Also I am not sure if Model should be passed to the method

Answer (score 1):

For information, I have remove the @ModelAttribute(name = "formTodo") because the error isn't displayed when I use it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/todo/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String tplTodoCreatePost(@Valid TodoForm todoForm, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirAttrs) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "v-todo-create";
    }

    todoRepository.save(todoForm);
    redirAttrs.addFlashAttribute("msgNotices", "Todo task created successfuly.");
    return "redirect:/todos";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the parameter Use Bindingresult result before the Model .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).